# Should Time Spent Studying Monsters Increase A Player's Intelligence Score?

Tags: monsters, ability-scores

I'm running a campaign where practically all of the classic monsters in the Manual have been killed off before any of the characters were born, and now they have returned from a villain basically resurrecting them. My question, then, is: if the players take the time to uncover knowledge about these monsters through a library or something, should their intelligence score increase? And if a veteran taught them about how to spot these monsters in the wild, should their Wisdom increase? I was thinking of just raising the stats by 1 if so.

(For context as far as the players go: I have a human Cleric with ~15 Wisdom, a human Rogue, a human Wizard with an Intelligence score of 10, and a half-elf Bard. So for the most part, the increases would be for skills/saving throws, and it could help out the characters who need those stats.)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. If you'd like the site to evaluate the balance implications of your house rule, that's something the site can do. What the site *can't* do, however, is assist you in *developing* your house rule or tell you if your general idea is acceptable—that's a discussion that's better to have on a traditional forum like one of [these](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610). However, once you get the specifics of your house rule hashed out, I'm certain the site'd be happy to help. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: Also, if you update the question with a specific houserule for us to evaluate, please also tag the question with which game you are playing.